# Why plugin's icon for the menu not found?

Tags: plugins, menus, admin, urls, icon

Why plugin's icon is not showing in plugin menu ?

All code of plugin :

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );

function register_my_custom_menu_page(){

    add_menu_page( 'Site Market', 'Site market', 'manage_options', 'market_admin/index.php', '', 
        plugins_url( 'market_admin/icon.png' ), 6 );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes i find wordpress can be quite finiky when it comes to referencing files within the plugin. Specifying a full path seems to fix the problem. Try replacing...

```
market_admin/icon.png
```

With...

```
/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin-name-goes-here/your-file-name-goes-here.png
```